# In Python3 , How to update the dict using comprehensions

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a List like this:

```
oldL = [
    {"id":1, "name":"aaa"},
    {"id":2, "name":"bbb"},
    {"id":3, "name":"ccc"},
]
```

and I want to convert to this:

```
newL = [
    {"id":1, "name":"aaa", "age":16},
    {"id":2, "name":"bbb", "age":16},
    {"id":3, "name":"ccc", "age":16}
]
```

By using "for structure" like this:

```
li = []
for sd in oldL:
    sd.update({"age":16})
    li.append(sd)
print(li)
```

I can get the right result, **But I want to use the Comprehensions, How to get it? Thanks a lot.**

I had test the case:

```
newL=[ sd.update({"age": 16}) for sd in oldL]
```

but I got `[None, None, None]`, because the return value of update() is None.

If I test the case like this:

```
detailL =[ (sd.update({"age": 16}), sd) for sd in schedule_detailL]
```

the result is :

```
[(None, {'id': 1, 'name': 'aaa', 'schedule_id': 1}), (None, {'id': 2, 'name': 'bbb', 'schedule_id': 1}), (None, {'id': 3, 'name': 'ccc', 'schedule_id': 1})]
```

Comment: You're mutating the original dicts instead of building new ones. Is that actually what you want? (Look at `oldL` after the loop completes.) If you want to mutate the input, then `li` is superfluous. If you don't want to mutate the input, you need to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3 you can use the [`**`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) dictionary unpacking operator to unpack the original dictionary and then create a new one with the addition of the `age` key:

```py
oldL = [
    {"id":1, "name":"aaa"},
    {"id":2, "name":"bbb"},
    {"id":3, "name":"ccc"},
]

newL = [ { **d, "age": 16 } for d in oldL ]
print(newL)
```

Output:

```py
[
 {'id': 1, 'name': 'aaa', 'age': 16},
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'bbb', 'age': 16},
 {'id': 3, 'name': 'ccc', 'age': 16}
]
```

Note that this creates *new* dictionaries; it does not update the old ones. To update the old ones requires the use of `update` in a loop e.g.

```py
for d in oldL:
    d.update({"age": 16})
print(oldL)
```

Output:

```py
[
 {'id': 1, 'name': 'aaa', 'age': 16},
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'bbb', 'age': 16},
 {'id': 3, 'name': 'ccc', 'age': 16}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `update` method of a dict updates that dict in-place, which is the reason you get `None` as the return value.
Basically, your comprehension works, you just updated it in-place.
However, using comprehensions for operations like this is usually unadvised.

If you instead want to create an actual new list of dicts, rather than updating the old one, you could do this:

```py
add_dct = {'age': 16}
newL = [{**sd, **add_dct} for sd in oldL]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I forget the ** operation!